# Totally bizzare: deleting a MySQL user allows me to still login as that user with an empty password

Tags: mysql, percona

Using MySQL 5.5 on Arch Linux, when I create a localhost user with a password and give it all privileges to all tables and then delete that user, I can still login as that user without typing in a password.

Steps to reproduce:

```
# mysql -u root -h localhost -p
  Enter password: <root password>

mysql> create user 'test'@'localhost' identified by 'testing123';
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'test'@'localhost' identified by 'testing123';
mysql> select * from mysql.user where user='test';
       1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> exit

# mysql -u test -h localhost -p
  Enter password: testing123

mysql> show databases;
mysql> exit

# mysql -u root -h localhost -p
  Enter password: <root password>

mysql> delete from mysql.user where user='test';
       Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> select * from mysql.user where user='test';
       Empty set (0.00 sec)
mysql> exit

# mysql -u test -h localhost

mysql> (Why?)
```

Not only that, but the "non-existing" test user can still exercise all of the same privileges. Major security problem. If I restart the server, it still lets me login without a password.

Comment: If you login as root and issue `select * from mysql.user where user='test';` again now, is the user shown or not? It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It is still showing "Empty set (0.00 sec)" (same result as when I tried it in my steps to reproduce above)

Comment: I've also tried restarting MySQL and even rebooting the entire machine a couple times. Same results for everything.

Comment: @DavidPesta: Have you done an upgrade on mySQL lately?

Comment: Perhaps some privilege table is corrupted. Check here for mysql-upgrade command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Comment: This is a fresh new install of Percona, a drop-in replacement of MySQL based on MySQL 5.5.12. The latest MySQL is 5.5.13 released 28 days ago. I'm thinking about installing the latest MySQL 5.5.13 to see if it happens on the most recent version.

Comment: CONFIRMED: I just installed the latest MySQL 5.5.13 and applied the above steps and got the exact same results! People need to start getting paranoid about old MySQL accounts that they THINK they deleted. Something tells me this isn't very uncommon and there are insecure accounts lingering everywhere, accessible by username only.

Comment: Also, I get the same exact result when I use "drop user": drop user 'test'@'localhost';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out what was happening. By default, in the user table there is an anonymous user @ localhost. This user is automatically matched with any attempted username and logged in as that anonymous user. Kind of strange, I know. To get rid of the anonymous user, login as root and perform the following command:

```
drop user ''@localhost;
```

Comment: Yes, as it says in this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html **"If you want to prevent clients from connecting as anonymous users without a password, you should either assign a password to each anonymous account or else remove the accounts."**

Comment: Thanks for this. Was having a different issue where a user I created with a password wasn't allowed when using the password, but was allowed in WITHOUT a password. Dropped the anon user and I'm back in business.